# Regex: symbols before and after the word should have the same amount

Tags: java, regex

I want to work on a type of regular expression that works out if a string has the same amount of asteriks before and after a word.

So to say the same amount of asteriks the left side as on the right side. I've come up with `\*+T\*+` where T is any non-asteriks word (simplified for this question). This also counts in ****hello* in "****hello****" for example, which I don't want. What it should only find is `hello, *hello* , **hello**, ***hello***, ****hello****` in `****hello****`

Is there a way in Java, or generally, to use a variable amount of lengths more than once, something along the lines of `\*{x}T\*{x}`. In which both sides "*" have the same amount of * concatenated at the end and the beginning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex,

```
(?<!\*)(\**)\b\w+\b(\1)(?!\*)
```

This will either match only word like `hello` or `*hello*` or `***hello***` but not match `*hello***`

**Explanation:**

- `\b\w+\b` --> This part enables it to just match a word like `hello`
- `(\**)` --> This part captures zero or more asterisk and captures them in group 1 to back reference them to match at the end of word and only if exactly same amount of asterisks are found, it gets successful match.
- `(?<!\*)` and `(?!\*)` --> Negative look ahead ensures it doesn't do a partial match in a larger string and only find a match that are not preceded or succeeded by asterisk characters.

**[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cCfnvo/1/)**